# Android - Save location in SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqldatatypes

I have problem with save latitude and longitude in SQLite database. I can save some location like (123.123999, 123.123999) and it will save in the database.
But if I want to read it, I get rounded location like (123.124, 123.124).

My table created by this sql segment:

```
CREATE TABLE locs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, lat DOUBLE, lng DOUBLE, num INTEGER)
```

And querys results:

```
SELECT * FROM locs WHERE lat = 123.124; //RETURN NO ROWS
SELECT * FROM locs WHERE lat = 123.123999; //RETURN 1 ROW
```

So I can't use the numbers I get to do queries on the data.

I believe that I am not the first that handling with this problem, because it is basic thing. But I didn't found any answers that work on SQLite database.

How can I read and write the correct number in the db?

Comment: add code how you are retrieving them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I read and write the correct number in the db?

I suggest you an one quick solution.

Since you know in what format you are storing your coordinates e.q. numbers so there is no problem to store them as `TEXT` and then retrieve them as `TEXT` and simple perform parsing back to `DOUBLE` if you'll want to do some stuff with them.

```
CREATE TABLE locs(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   lat TEXT,
   lng TEXT,
   num INTEGER
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define an epsilon around the queried value, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM locs WHERE lat BETWEEN value-epsilon AND value+epsilon;
```

You can change your epsilon according to your need. In the example you gave 1e-3 should suffice.

Another option is to round the values when you insert them, but then you'll lose information you might need down the road.

Comment: My real critical problem is that I get rounded value. How they didn't thought about solution for this problem...  
And in your first way you need epsilon 1e-3 because 123.1235 will also rounded to 123.124

Comment: You are correct, sir. Corrected in the post. However if the fact that you get a rounded value is what concerns you - you should also post the code that you use to retrieve it.

Comment: I just don't know how this round affects on the real location, no meter what is my code, its wrong. (I just show the points on map)